# What to say before starting your prayers?

Tags: salat

I remember when starting prayers you say something before the Fatiha.

It was something like "Oh allah, I'm about to start praying Isha, please accept it" it was right after the Adhan and when you put your hands up behind your ears.

Can someone tell me what it was?

Answer (score -1):

"Allaho akbar" , we call it *takbiratolehram*, and it means Allah is the greatest.

Comment: Allaho akbar is said as well but even before that there was something else if I remember correctly. You say the Adhan, then you state your prayers. You say whether you're doing your Duhr, Asr, Maghrib, Isha etc... prayers.

Comment: you are talking about "Niyyat" "نیت" , some say what they are doing, but you are not forced to say it , you should only know what you are doing.